# Cell background colour only shows up to the text

Tags: cocoa-touch

I have gone as far as to use the following code to set the background colour of a TableView cell (in cellForRowAtIndexPath)

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;


        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];

        UIView* backgroundView = [ [ [ UIView alloc ] initWithFrame:CGRectZero ] autorelease ];
        backgroundView.backgroundColor = [ UIColor yellowColor ];
        cell.backgroundView = backgroundView;
        for ( UIView* view in cell.contentView.subviews ) 
        {
            view.backgroundColor = [ UIColor yellowColor ];
        }
    }

    // Set up the cell...
    if ([[menuList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isKindOfClass:[Category  class]])
    {
        cell.text = ((Category *)[menuList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]).name;
    }
    else
    {
        [cell setText: [menuList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    }


    return cell;
}
```

However when it renders only part of the cell has the background applied kind of like this (where z is the bg fill), even the background of the Accessory is colour but not the text.

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
zzzSearch          
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

The only way I see to be able to change the background of the text is by setting the background colour of the whole table view in Interface Builder

Answer (score 0):

I bet your text is an opaque UILabel.  I remember having to add `myText.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]` to the content text UILabel to get this to work right.

Comment: Thanks sounds like a promising root to the solution. I have tried what you suggested (see updated code sample above), but still no joy, any suggestions?

Comment: Not easily no as Im a bit of a mac newb, but Im sure it is what you suggest. I think the label is simply not opaque. But as you can see above Im trying all I can think of. Have I missed something obvious?

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to do it using a Custom TableViewCell object, but Im sure there must be a way to do it without